# MongoDB atlas says '404 Document not found' when clicking on collections

Tags: database, mongodb, collections, document, mongodb-atlas

I was using a cluster for my MERN app. The IP address and database user is configured and it was working till yesterday. Today, when I click on collections, a 404 page appears. What might be the problem?

Comment: It happened to me too, after some time it started working again.

Comment: yes, it worked after a while